# Installing React on brackets?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I downloaded react from node and deleted everything in src, then I created 3 files. Index.html, index. js and styles.css. I then select the src folder and opened it as a brackets project. I import React and ReactDOM. Then on the node terminal I did npm run and the header element in the js file showed up. Then I added a header element in the HTML. On the live preview on brackets only the HTML header shows up and on the React window only the react header shows up. Does anyone understand what is going on, because I have spent hours trying to sort this out. There is a script reference in the HTML.
EDIT: I put the HTML file in the public folder and have type="text/jsx" references in the html but when I do live preview (not from localhost) only the html shows up. Is this normal? Also nothing is auto updating, I have to save for the changes to show... When I enter in localhost then all the html and react headers are visible. I have been working on this all day and I feel like there is a simple fix that I am not seeing.

Edit 2 : Added code

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(<h1>this is REACT</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link type="text/css" href="../src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
   <h1>this is header text from html...................</h1>
   <h1>this is another headerfrom html</h1>
 
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="../src/App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="../src/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

your src folder should have index.js and App.js and other JS and CSS  files **but not HTML file**, the HTML file should be inside your public folder. similar to the picture

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for the React but still has not fixed the live preview? would I just change the server to localhost and does that imply I can't run it from the html script? Also I believe I deleted app.js.

Comment: Also, when I set my project like the image, it says error indexing files, project contains over 30,000 files and that some features may be disabled. Is this normal?

Comment: i honestly don't understand what you mean but i would suggest you delete the file you have, then go to the command line and write `create-react-app`  then go to the directory  and run `npm start` @Zarg

Comment: basically what I mean is when I try to run the html which is associated with the javascript files it does not show any of the javascript functions only the html content. Thanks for your help so far! (I reinstalled it now) @Zaid

Comment: Also the files are not auto updating on the screen. I have to save for my headers to change.

Answer (score 0):

[image: React tutorial - Local development setup]

This will help you to install / setup react in your local with your preferred text editor.

link: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment

Comment: Hi those were the instructions I followed. It is my understanding that React automatically updates? It is not doing that in brackets when I change something. It works when I save. Also I guess instead of running the index.html you have to run localhost instead, is that correct (otherwise it only shows the html for me)? When I do it using the SDK it works when I just run the index.html file for some reason.